# Pygame being really slow blitting images on android

Tags: android, pygame

I am trying to use pygame and pygame_sdl2 to make a game for android, and then use pgs4a to compile it to apk.

I use `.fill()` as background at first and it worked normaly, but when I tried to blit an image as background, my program became really laggy on my phone. Everything works fine on PC.

Here is my code.

It just simply show your finger pos and count how many times you have touched the screen.

```
import pygame_sdl2
pygame_sdl2.import_as_pygame()

import pygame
import os

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((360,640))
    sleeping = False
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    font = pygame.font.Font("data/DejaVuSans.ttf", 48)
    background = pygame.image.load("image/background.jpg").convert()
    background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (screen.get_width(),screen.get_width()))
    press = 0

    while running:
        clock.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_AC_BACK:
                running = False

            elif event.type == pygame.APP_WILLENTERBACKGROUND:
                sleeping = True
            elif event.type == pygame.APP_DIDENTERFOREGROUND:
                sleeping = False
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode((360,640))

            elif event.type == pygame.FINGERDOWN:
                press += 1

        if not sleeping:
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            screen.blit(background, (0.5*(screen.get_width()-background.get_width()),0.5*(screen.get_height()-background.get_height())))
            text = font.render(str((x,y,press)), True, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(text, (0.5*(screen.get_width()-text.get_width()),0.5*(screen.get_height()-text.get_height())))
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have seen many people make their games through pygame and seems to work perfectly. Is there anything wrong with my code or something I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

pygame_sdl2 on Android have an other behavior!

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((360,640))
```

on Windows, this line creates a window with size 360x640.

on Android, the window is always fullscreen with the device native resolution. For example: 1080x1920.

So, blitting on Windows needs 360x640 = **230400 pixels to draw.**

On Android: 1080x1920 = **2073600 pixels to draw** which is 9 times more.

I have the same problem! I asked the devs on github. But still no satisfying solution. https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2/issues/69